# Normal distribution problem

Tags: statistics

Hello Mathematics dep!

Variate $X$, which follows the normal distribution, has median $\mu = 14$ and variance $\sigma ^2 = 9$. What are the odds that $X > 12$.

Attempt at a solution: $P(X>12) = 1 - P(X \leq 12)$
\begin{equation}
z = \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma} = \frac{12 - 14}{3} = -2/3
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-z ^2 /2} = \frac{1}{3 \cdot \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-(-2/3)^2 /2} = 0.106482669
\end{equation}
$1 - 0.106482669 = 0.893517331$ which is the wrong answer. Any pointers would be appreciated; I've grown tired of having this problem defeating me.

Thanks.

Comment: You're using the pdf instead of the cdf.

Comment: P(X<=12)=P(Z<=-2/3).  So look for the probability in the standard normal table for the cumulative probability correcponding to x=-2/3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up the answer in a z-table, after finding the z-score.